# How do I make Vite build exit with a non-zero code?

Tags: reactjs, build, vite

I am migrating a React App in TypeScript to Vite. I love it!

I am trying to setup our CI with GitHub Actions. But I want the build to fail if it has any errors. I find 100s of posts online about people complaining about `vite build` failures, but I cannot find an answer on how to actually for `vite build` to fail.

In particular, here is the error that is being reported that I want to fail the build for:

```
Export "useFoobar" of module "src/Shared/useFoobar.ts" was reexported through module "src/Shared/index.ts" while both modules are dependencies of each other and will end up in different chunks by current Rollup settings. This scenario is not well supported at the moment as it will produce a circular dependency between chunks and will likely lead to broken execution order.
Either change the import in "src/MyComponent.ts" to point directly to the exporting module or reconfigure "output.manualChunks" to ensure these modules end up in the same chunk.
```

Similarly, there is a warning about chunk size at the bottom of the report that I would like to consider failing the build for:

[image: rollup summary warning]

Comment: These are warnings, not errors. There's a recent open question [here](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/discussions/16050) you can follow. In the meantime, I'd recommend solving the circular dependency issue using a [lint rule](https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import/blob/main/docs/rules/no-cycle.md)

Comment: You can check out various projects to help you enforce bundle size as well - here’s [one example](https://github.com/ai/size-limit)

Comment: @AdamJenkins any recommendations on how to match my linting rules to what the build does? I had tried running the default lint rules that came with the project but it did not detect those particular build warnings.

Comment: There's no way to match the lint rules of a project with the build system that project is using. You configure your linter the way you want, to the preferences of you and your team. It sounds like you want the no circular dependency lint rule that I mentioned above. I personally include that one in all my projects.